# Network layer : the working of ARP( address resolution protocol)

Tags: mac-address

If the switches have MAC tables, then what is the need of ARP table in the host systems that stores MAC addresses of other end systems?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are totally unrelated.

- the MAC address table in a switch memorizes which device is connected to which port on the switch.
- the ARP table on a host memorizes which MAC address is associated with a given IP address.

Answer (score 2):

The IP address is used for addressing a host on the network layer (L3).

Switches however are data link layer devices (L2) that know nothing about IP and L3. They require a MAC address for addressing - this MAC address has to be determined by the L3 device (a host or a router) before being able to pass an IP packet over Ethernet. IPv4 uses ARP while IPv6 uses NDP.

With the destination MAC address from the Ethernet frame, the switch can then forward the frame to the L2 destination efficiently (the L2 destination is a local host or the next hop router).

(*Switches know nothing about IP* is only true for pure L2 switches - multi-layer switches do know L3 (or even L4) protocols, and they're partially routers in this sense.)